# Number as key in array gives error offset 1 - PHP

Tags: php, laravel

My Question is, i got an array with mix keys (i mean numeric and string);

This is my code sample,

```
 Array
 (
   [_id] => 1, [month] => 052014, [studId] => STU140528155358,
   [1] => 'p', [2] => , [3] => ,[4] => ,[12] => 'a'

 )
```

Now I try to

```
  print_r($array[3]);
```

It gives error undefined offset 3

SAMPLE:-

Run This:

$a = array("name"=>"Nishchit",[1]=>"Dhanani");

print_r($a[1]);

Comment: does print_r($array['3']) work?

Comment: yup - It gives, ErrorException Undefined offset:3

Comment: Can you create a online fiddle for it ?

Comment: Please remove these keys from the array.
[2] => , [3] => ,[4] => 

You can assign null values (''), if needed, like - [2] => '', [3] => '', [4] => ''

Comment: Rikesh- Goto phpcodepad.com and run this $a = array("name"=>"Nishchit",[1]=>"Dhanani");

print_r($a[1]);

Comment: You mean `$a = array("name"=>"Nishchit",1=>"Dhanani");`?

Comment: Nischit - this works: $a = array("name"=>"Nishchit",1=>"Dhanani");
print_r($a[1]);   - its what @KunalDethe said - your creating the array wrong

Comment: Try `var_dump` instead of `print_r`, also try `var_dump(array_keys($array))`.

Comment: But all this will work only if you have the array keys with some value. If any of the keys don't have a value then it will throw an error.

Comment: @Kunal That's nonsense. All keys always have values, or they wouldn't exist. A key either exists or it doesn't, its value is irrelevant.

Comment: I am referring to the point made by @Prava - Mindfire Solutions. Try removing the empty keys and `print_r()`. It works. Mixed array keys are not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This will work-

```
$a = array("name"=>"Nishchit",1=>"Dhanani");

print_r($a[1]);
```

You have done a mistake of putting `[1]` instead of just `1` as key.

And if you  want a nested array, you can do this -

```
$a = array("name"=>"Nishchit",[1=>"Dhanani"]);

print_r($a[0]);
print_r($a[0][1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array(
   '_id' => 1, 
   'month' => 052014, 
   'studId' => STU140528155358, 
   1 => 'p', 
   12 => 'a'
);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($a[1]);
```

Output -

`p`

---

```
$b = array(
   '_id' => 1, 
   'month' => 052014, 
   'studId' => STU140528155358, 
   1 => 'p',
   2 => '',
   12 => 'a'
);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($b[12]);
```

Output -

`a`